# Get all posts by many custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, get-posts

**Question:**
I have many custom post types and i want to return all the posts by just a few of the post types:

For example i have an array and was wondering if there was a way of passing this array to something like the get_posts function and it returning all the post types specified in the array.

Example array:

```
post_types = [ 
event,
award,
upcoming 
]
```

The above array would be passed to said function and i would be returned all posts matching only those in the array,

Comment: There's that exact parameter documented in the official `WP_Query` reference page with examples

Comment: @TomJNowell looks perfect thank you.